# Controls need to stay centered when resizing (responsive UI, JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, responsive, scenebuilder

I have this code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LoginController">
    <children>
          <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" height="151.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" width="1366.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
             <fill>
                <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="0.5491606714628298" startX="0.36930455635491605" startY="0.8920863309352518">
                   <stops>
                      <Stop color="BLACK" />
                      <Stop color="#2f406b" offset="1.0" />
                   </stops>
                </LinearGradient>
             </fill>
          </Rectangle>
          <ImageView fx:id="ivWordCrex" fitHeight="115.0" fitWidth="105.0" layoutX="631.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
             <image>
                <Image url="@../../resources/WordCrex_Logo.png" />
             </image>
          </ImageView>
          <Label fx:id="lblLogin" layoutX="655.0" layoutY="201.0" text="Login">
             <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
             </font>
          </Label>
          <Pane layoutX="502.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="363.0">
             <children>
                <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="icoUser" glyphName="USER" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="100.0" size="30" text="" />
                <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="icoLock" glyphName="LOCK" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="163.0" size="30" />
                <JFXTextField fx:id="txtUName" layoutX="70.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="225.0" promptText="gebruikersnaam">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                   </font>
                </JFXTextField>
                <JFXPasswordField fx:id="txtPass" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="225.0" promptText="wachtwoord">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                   </font>
                </JFXPasswordField>
                <JFXButton fx:id="btnLogin" defaultButton="true" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="214.0" onAction="#login" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="175.0" style="-fx-background-color: #384667;" text="Inloggen" textFill="WHITE">
                   <font>
                      <Font size="16.0" />
                   </font>
                </JFXButton>
             </children>
          </Pane>
          <Label fx:id="lblWordCrex" layoutX="636.0" layoutY="119.0" text="WordCrex" textFill="WHITE">
             <font>
                <Font size="20.0" />
             </font>
          </Label>    
     </children> 
</AnchorPane>
```

This is how it looks **default**.

[image]

When I'm making the window **bigger** it looks like this.

[image]

And when I'm making the window **smaller** it looks like this.

[image]

**I want to make this scene responsive, so that the banner on top goes the whole width of the window, the image (the throphy) centered and all of the 'login' controls centered in the page.**

I've already tried with a bunch of different pane's, but I still can't figure it out. As you can see the AnchorPane has those AnchorPane.'direction'anchor = "0.0", but that's also not working for me. I got that from this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_v58NRTOTM&.

So if anyone could help me with figuring out how to make this scene responsive, I'd appreciate it a lot!

EDIT:

I now have this, but even here it won't resize with the window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>


<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0">
         <children>
            <Rectangle fill="#1d288a" height="150.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" width="1366.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Try considering to layout using StackPane, HBox, VBox, GridPane etc by setting the layout policy. This will solve your responsive problem.

Comment: @SaiDandem Could you look at the edit I made?

Comment: Try removing the AnchorPane. Here you dont need an extra wrapper to your Rectangle.Just place the Rectangle as the children to the StackPane and remove all the AnchorPane stuff you defined in Rectangle. By default StackPane aligns its children to CENTER. You can change that by updating the alignment attribute. Also try considering @fabian answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Rectangle`s are not resizable. You should use `Region` or a subtype instead and apply the gradient as background.

Furthermore `AnchorPane` is no good for centering nodes. If you just want to center the login controls horizontally only, I recommend wrapping everything in a `VBox`. Otherwise wrap those controls in a `StackPane` and this to the `VBox`

```xml
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1366.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LoginController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="151.0" style="-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, #2f406b 100%)">
         <children>
            <VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
              <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="ivWordCrex" fitHeight="115.0" fitWidth="105.0"  pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                  <image>
                    <Image url="@../../resources/WordCrex_Logo.png" />
                  </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Label fx:id="lblWordCrex" text="WordCrex" textFill="WHITE">
                  <font>
                    <Font size="20.0" />
                  </font>
                </Label>
              </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
               <children>
                   <Label fx:id="lblLogin" text="Login">
                       <font>
                           <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
                       </font>
                  </Label>
                  <GridPane>
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" />
                      <ColumnConstraints prefWidth="225.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="icoUser" glyphName="USER" size="30" text="" />
                        <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="icoLock" glyphName="LOCK"  size="30" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <JFXTextField fx:id="txtUName" prefHeight="26.0" promptText="gebruikersnaam" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="16.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXTextField>
                        <JFXPasswordField fx:id="txtPass" prefHeight="26.0" promptText="wachtwoord" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="16.0" />
                           </font>
                        </JFXPasswordField>
                    </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <JFXButton fx:id="btnLogin" defaultButton="true" onAction="#login" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="175.0" style="-fx-background-color: #384667;" text="Inloggen" textFill="WHITE">
                      <font>
                          <Font size="16.0" />
                      </font>
                  </JFXButton>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I'll try to experiment with this to find my ideal solution. But is it possible to set on the outer VBox a min width and height? I've done this in the properties, but I can still resize below that.

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays The scene root can be forced to resize below the minimum size. If you want to prevent this, you should do so using the properties of `Stage`.

Comment: Got it, but somehow I can still change the height a bit, which is weird because it's exactly the same. `stage.setMinHeight(768);` `stage.setMinWidth(1366);`